# OCI runtime failed container_linux:345 starting container process caused process_linux init caused rootfs_linux:58 mounting caused perm deni unknown

Tags: docker, unity-game-engine, vps, ubuntu-18.04, cockroachdb

I'm setting up [Nakama](https://heroiclabs.com/docs/install-docker-quickstart/) for a personal Unity3D project.

Normally it has to return to a normal command-line. Like `user@vps-24-nextwab:~$`

I use Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

I tried on two different VPS, with a root and non-root user.

What I type:

```
sudo docker run --name=db -p 26257 -p 8080 cockroachdb/cockroach start --insecure
```

The output is:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused
>   "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58:
>   mounting \\"proc\\" to rootfs
>   \\"/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/7c1c7c17556e9d13882fb75c32952a72b3e25cfd9ce992958d6750b5e72bbc5e\\"
>   at \\"/proc\\" caused \\"permission denied\\"\"": unknown.

Comment: Seems pretty weird, and I could not reproduce it with Docker `19.03.1, build 74b1e89` on Ubuntu 18.04. Could you try fresh version of Docker?

Comment: This: `--name=db-p 26257 -p 8080` looks strange. Are you missing a space between `db` and `-p 26257`? If that's the case, please [edit] your question and provide the correct command line.

Comment: I missed a space

Comment: Nothing changed, same error. Thanks

Comment: This looks like a problem with mounting/volumes.

Comment: @FruityLabel were you using with lxc?